# Cordova/android application displayed with upper case letters only

Tags: android, cordova

Why is my Cordova/android application displaying all text in capital letters? For example:

Code:

```
<title>My Application</title>
```

Android page:

```
MY APPLICATION
```

Code:

```
Login:
```

Android page:

```
LOGIN:
```

Answer (score 3):

It was due to the default css style generated  by cordova's create command (index.css) :
body {
    . . .
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

find cordova's index.css 
you will find this:
text-transform:uppercase;
comment this line.